# Spring cloud gateway GET api is working fine but POST is not

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm new to Spring cloud and spring backend development. I'm trying to develop a simple microservice with spring cloud gateway.

Github links to [Discovery Server](https://github.com/Aritra1704/UdemyDiscoveryServer), [Spring Cloud Api Gateway](https://github.com/Aritra1704/UdemyApiGateway) and [User micro service](https://github.com/Aritra1704/UdemyUserApiUser). Astonishingly when I execute the APIs in Postman, the GET API works but not the POST.

I tried to debug, It didn't come to my Controller for POST. What am I missing? Or doing wrong?
Any help or suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Your configuration restricts the http method to GET `spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[1]=Method=GET`

Comment: You mean in API Gateway? Added POST along with GET.
Now its 

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[1]=Method=GET, POST, PUT, DELETE

Comment: and now what happens? please provide any error

Comment: No error logs or anything in any of the console(discovery, microservice or gateway). Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.
If anyone else has a similar problem.

I missed out on routes for POST API. Thanks, @spencergibb for the hint.

Comment: Hi Ari , i am trying to solve similar problem, where basically there is ask to POST data (same JSON schema) to different customers (endpoints), each with their own auth mechanism (1 customer with OAuth2, 2nd with Basic, 3rd with different OAuth2). I am exploring to solve this using Spring Cloud Gateway and tried to follow your github example. Could you share more insights how can Spring Cloud Gateway do POST with different auth mechanism applied to each route? pls refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75154968/system-design-to-flexibility-choose-rest-endpoint-with-applicable-security

Answer (score 0):

It may be a cross-domain problem
Here's an example

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PathPatternParser;

/**
 * @author beichenhpy
 * @version 0.0.1
 * @apiNote CorsConfig description：
 * @since 2021/5/9 9:45 下午
 */
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {
    private static final String ALLOWED_HEADERS = "x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN,token,username,client";
    private static final String ALLOWED_METHODS = "*";
    private static final String ALLOWED_ORIGIN = "*";
    private static final String ALLOWED_EXPOSE = "*";
    private static final Long MAX_AGE = 18000L;

    @Bean
    public CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter(){
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader(ALLOWED_HEADERS);
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod(ALLOWED_METHODS);
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin(ALLOWED_ORIGIN);
        corsConfiguration.addExposedHeader(ALLOWED_EXPOSE);
        corsConfiguration.setMaxAge(MAX_AGE);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource configurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource(new PathPatternParser());
        configurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**",corsConfiguration);
        return new CorsWebFilter(configurationSource);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand how can this be cross-domain problem, can you please elaborate a bit more? And if possible if you can pinpoint the root cause. I believe what I'm doing is pretty basic and any backend developer using spring boot must go through this process and this might be some silly mistake.